# How can I write this recursive algorithm to eat less memory?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, recursion, stack-overflow

I am trying to create my own WordSearch game for Windows Phone, and I found an algorithm for solving it. My problem is that the algorithm uses recursion and I'm getting a StackOverflowException after 6-8 calls.

- array : char[,] contains the characters of a 2D table
- i,a:    coordinates of the current position in the array
- width,height: size  of the array
- build: string we are trying to create(the word itself)
- covered: bool[,] is for the already used characters

Here is the algorithm:

```
...
enum WordType : byte
    {
        FullWord,
        PartialWord,
        FullWordAndPartialWord
    }  
...
static Dictionary<string, WordType> _words = new Dictionary<string, WordType>();
static Dictionary<string, bool> _found = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

void Search(char[,] array, int i, int a, int width, int height, string build, bool[,] covered)
        {            
            if (i >= width || i < 0 || a >= height || a < 0)
            {
                return;
            }            
            if (covered[a, i])
            {
                return;
            }

            char letter = array[a, i];

            string pass = build + letter;            
            WordType value;
            if (_words.TryGetValue(pass, out value))
            {                
                if (value == WordType.FullWord ||
                value == WordType.FullWordAndPartialWord)
                {                    
                    if (!_found.ContainsKey(pass))
                    {                        
                        _found.Add(pass, true);
                    }
                }

                if (value == WordType.PartialWord ||
                value == WordType.FullWordAndPartialWord)
                {

                    bool[,] cov = new bool[height, width];
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < width; i2++)
                    {
                        for (int a2 = 0; a2 < height; a2++)
                        {
                            cov[a2, i2] = covered[a2, i2];
                        }
                    }

                    cov[a, i] = true;

                    Search(array, i + 1, a, width, height, pass, cov);
                    Search(array, i, a + 1, width, height, pass, cov);
                    Search(array, i + 1, a + 1, width, height, pass, cov);
                    Search(array, i - 1, a, width, height, pass, cov);
                    Search(array, i, a - 1, width, height, pass, cov);
                    Search(array, i - 1, a - 1, width, height, pass, cov);
                    Search(array, i - 1, a + 1, width, height, pass, cov);
                    Search(array, i + 1, a - 1, width, height, pass, cov);
                }
            }
        }
```

And when I'm calling it:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < height; a++)
                {
                    Search(array, i, a, width, height, "", covered);
                }
            }
```

What can I do to avoid the Exception ?

Comment: Look into "Tail recursion"

Comment: Why are you calling Search(array, i + 1, a, width, height, pass, cov) and 7 other calls with +1 and -1 INSIDE the method, when you are stepping threw an array for i and a OUTSIDE of it? Wouldnt it be enough to just leave the other call and remove the 8 calls inside it?

Comment: @kostyan: With c# "Tail recursion" isn't guaranteed on all architectures. Last time I looked, only x64 .net tried it.

Comment: What kind of wordsearch allows you to go off in any direction after the second letter? Searches will end up wondering all over the board. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @spender Yes, that is what I want to do.

Comment: @kostyan I've searched after this, but I still don't know how can I use that.

Comment: @RandRandom When I'm stepping through the array outside, it determines the starting letter of the word. Inside the method, I search for the other letters, and I have to do that in any possible way, to get a "good" word.